# How to match only vertical tab?

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I am trying to strip out vertical tab characters. I have tried using `\v` but this seems to match newline characters as well:

`$str =~ s/\v/ /;`

How can I match only vertical tab characters in perl?

Comment: How would warnings help?

Comment: @ CJ7: warnings always help.  @ikegami: the "seems to match newline" makes me think it may not be matching \v, and they may be using an old perl that doesn't support \v.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\v` doesn't just match line tabulations (vertical tabs); it matches all vertical whitespace characters.

```
$ unichars '\v' | cat
 ---- U+000A LINE FEED
 ---- U+000B LINE TABULATION
 ---- U+000C FORM FEED
 ---- U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
 ---- U+0085 NEXT LINE
 ---- U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
 ---- U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
```

You want to match U+000B LINE TABULATION exclusively. You can use any of the following:

```regex
\x0B
\x{B}
\x{0B}
\x{000B}
\x{00000B}
\013
\cK
\N{U+B}
\N{U+000B}
\N{U+00000B}
\N{LINE TABULATION}
\N{VT}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html):

```
$str =~ /\cK/;  # Matches if $str contains a vertical tab (control-K).
```

Comment: An example of string would be helpful.

Comment: @user2705585, `$str = "\cK";`